# How to set dylib search path OSX

Tags: macos, linker, cmake, dyld, rpath

I have a project in Xcode where I set DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH in the environment variables pane to set where my application should look for libraries to link to (which works well for my purposes)

[image]

I am writing a CMakeLists.txt file to generate this project now and I would like to set this property from the script.

I am aware I can do this:

```
SET(ENV{DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH} ${DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH} /path/to/lib)
```

but when I run I get this error:

```
'dyld: Library not loaded ... Reason: image not found'
```

when launching the application. I imagine the statement is not the same.

Does someone know how I can achieve the equivalent of what I have in Xcode from CMakeLists.txt?

I am vaguely aware of the CMake RPATH stuff but I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Thank you for your time!

Cheers!

Tom

Comment: `I am vaguely aware of the CMake RPATH stuff but I'd rather avoid that if possible.` - But this is the proper way for do things you want. See https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling for more info. `SET(ENV{..})` sets environment variable only on `cmake` run stage, it doesn't affect on environment for build or run stages.

Comment: Hi! I should probably have emphasised vaugely... :P My situation is I have a dylib (in this case SDL) that I want to link at runtime, but I do not want to have to add it to the system path (/usr/local/bin..) I had a look into the RPATH stuff but it all just looked super convoluted. I have read through that article and tried some of the CMake stuff it says to use but didn't have much luck. Do I have to do the dylib install_name_tool thing? I wanted to avoid that as it seemed a bit weird. My background is mainly Windows so maybe I'm missing something obvious! Thanks!

Comment: If you have problems when follow given CMake article about RPATH, describe that specific problems.

Comment: In the link you mention, I attempted to use the CMake example under the section 'Always full RPATH' - but I wasn't sure if I needed to modify my existing dylib. If I run otool -L, the paths are absolute, and my app is looking for my shared lib in usr/local/bin (where it isn't) I don't really want to modify the dylib if I can help it, and I haven't built that myself.

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but if somebody else wants to avoid the `@rpath` stuff and comes across this post, just call your compiled program like `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path to lib> ./<program>`. Credit: https://superuser.com/a/282451

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I did finally get this working using a slightly different approach. This might not be the perfect solution and work in all cases, but hopefully this will help someone who is having similar problems to me.

The dylib I was trying to link to was `libSDL2-2.0.0`

If I navigate to where that file is located and run:

```
otool -L libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib
```

the top line I get in the output is this:

```
/usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib
```

if I then navigate to my built executable and run the same command, I see the same thing:

```
/usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib
```

(my executable links to SDL)

My problem was `libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib` is not actually located there, it's in my project structure in a libs folder. In order to get the linker to find the lib at runtime, I had to run this command on the dylib

```
install_name_tool -id "@executable_path/../path/to/lib/<lib_name>" <lib_name>
```

where `@executable_path` is the location of the application to run - in my case this was in - `build/debug`

The project structure:

```
root/
    CMakeLists.txt
    project/
        lib/
            libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib
    build/
        debug/
            my_app
```

This is an exact mapping for clarity:

```
install_name_tool -id "@executable_path/../../project/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib" libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib
```

If I run `otool -L libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib` I now see:

```
@executable_path/../../sdl-test/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib
```

in the first line of the output.

If I now build my project again (I'm just building in Xcode), this updates my app with the new relative path to the dylib. You only have to run `install_name_tool` on the library, you do not also have to run it on your executable, it will be updated when you build it.

If I run `otool -L myapp` I now see the same relative path to `libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib`

With that, when launching the app it was able to successfully find the dylib!

My understanding is that this is the way to achieve this on OSX and there isn't a brilliant alternative (other than messing with `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` which I mentioned in my question)

I hope this has been of some help to someone who had similar difficulties to me!

Resources I found useful:

http://osiris.laya.com/coding/dylib_linking.html

https://www.fmod.org/questions/question/forum-23398/

https://blogs.oracle.com/dipol/entry/dynamic_libraries_rpath_and_mac

**UPDATE:**

I actually found an even better way to do this using rpaths and thought I'd write up how to do this for future reference:

In my CMakeLists.txt file I added these lines right at the end (after `add_executable` and `target_link_libraries`:

```
# set @rpaths for libraries to link against
set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  FALSE)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE) 
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${PROJ_LIB_DIR}")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
```

(see https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling for more info)

where `${PROJ_LIB_DIR}` is where my dylibs are located:

```
set(PROJ_LIB_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib)
```

I then ran:

example:

```
install_name_tool -id "@rpath/<my-dylib>.dylib" <my-dylib>.dylib
```

actual:

```
install_name_tool -id "@rpath/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib" libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib
```

in the directory where my dylib is located (in my case libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib)

Now when I run cmake and then build my project, my new executable will search for the library in the location I set in the CMakeLists.txt file at runtime. `@rpath` will be substituted with the path specified in the CMakeLists.txt file and everything just works without explicitly having to set the `@executable_path` or `@loader_path`